# fastest way to insert multiple rows into a dataframe given a list of indexes (python)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, insert, concatenation

I have a dataframe and I would like to insert rows at specific indexes at the beginning of each group within the dataframe. As an example lets say I have the following dataframe:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[['A',1,1],['A',2,3],['A',5,4],['B',3,4],['B',2,6],['B',8,4],['C',9,3],['C',3,7],['C',1,9],['D',5,5],['D',8,3],['D',4,7]], columns=['Group','val1','val2'])
```

I would like to copy the first row of each unique value in the column group and insert that row at the beginning of each group while growing the dataframe. I can currently achieve this by using a for loop but it is pretty slow because my dataframe is large so I am looking for a vectorized solution.

I have a list of indexes where I would like to insert the rows.

```py
idxs = [0, 3, 6, 9]
```

In each iteration of the loop I currently slice the dataframe at each one of the idxs into two dataframes, insert the row, and concat the dataframes. My dataframe is very large so this process has been very slow.

The solution would look like this:

```py
   Group  val1  val2
0      A     1     1
1      A     1     1
2      A     2     3
3      A     5     4
4      B     3     4
5      B     3     4
6      B     2     6
7      B     8     4
8      C     9     3
9      C     9     3
10     C     3     7
11     C     1     9
12     D     5     5
13     D     5     5
14     D     8     3
15     D     4     7
```

Comment: Must the row be inserted at the beginning of its group? And why? This seems counter to what pandas is built to do. There are very fast ways to get the first row of each group and put them all at the _end_ or _beginning_ of the DataFrame.

Comment: Hi @brentertainer, I'm actually breaking the dataframe into multiple dataframes, putting the data at the beginning of each and then concating them back to one. The reason I need them as one large dataframe is because I perform a lot of calculations on the columns and it is much faster to do it via a vectorized approach rather than loop through each of the sub dataframes. The row at the beginning is necessary for some of the calculation conventions that come later.

Comment: I see. I know my approach for forming the initial DataFrame is a little  slow, so I am happy to read that its a means to a more efficiently obtained end!

Comment: Your method was still about 20% faster than mine so thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by grouping by `group`, iterating over each group, and constructing a DataFrame via concatenation of each the first row of a group to the group itself, then the concatenation of all those concatenations.

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[['A',1,1],['A',2,3],['A',5,4],['B',3,4],['B',2,6],['B',8,4],['C',9,3],['C',3,7],['C',1,9],['D',5,5],['D',8,3],['D',4,7]], columns=['Group','val1','val2'])

df_new = pd.concat([
    pd.concat([grp.iloc[[0], :], grp])
    for key, grp in df.groupby('Group')
])
print(df_new)
```

**Output:**

```
   Group  val1  val2
0      A     1     1
0      A     1     1
1      A     2     3
2      A     5     4
3      B     3     4
3      B     3     4
4      B     2     6
5      B     8     4
6      C     9     3
6      C     9     3
7      C     3     7
8      C     1     9
9      D     5     5
9      D     5     5
10     D     8     3
11     D     4     7
```